# Set different middleware for a subroute in go-chi

Tags: go, go-chi, httprouter

I have a proxy server that can be deactivated by config, with `mustBeSecure`. I want this proxy to act different in a certain subdomain: "/application/health", allowing it always insecure. All changes i've tried so far have failed. Is there a way to configure a different group for "/application/health" that still uses the proxy but never requires authentication?

```golang
router := chi.NewRouter()
router.Route("/", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(chimw.Recoverer)
    router.Use(hlog.NewHandler(log.Logger))
    if mustBeSecure() {
        r.Use(keycloak.MustStandardKeycloakAuth("url"))
    }
    setProxy(r)
    r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Get("/health", handleHealth())
    })
})
return http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0", router)
```

As requested, here is an example of what does setProxy()

```golang
func setProxy(r chi.Router) {
    r.Route("/application", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
            return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "target", "http:locahost:9999")
                r = r.WithContext(ctx)
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            })
        })
        r.HandleFunc("/*", httputil.ReverseProxy{}.ServeHTTP)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `setProxy` is doing? At least an abbreviated version

Comment: I did. I hope it makes sense. I'm really not fluent with go and go-chi

Comment: It helps, thank. I'm still not sure about the final goal tho. Can you check if it's this?
a) keycloak auth is used based on config value; 
b) if enabled, keycloak auth is a middleware for all /application/... routes;
c) /application/health should always be public

Comment: Yes. Thats what i would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying this.

- use a router for all `/application` routes
- declare `GET /health`
- create a group for all other routes (in `/application`)
- apply conditional middleware

I've simplified the code a bit just for ease of understanding. You can still use your `setProxy` function.

```
func main() {
    proxy, err := NewProxy("http://localhost:4422")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    router := chi.NewRouter()

    router.Get("/health", handleHealth)

    router.Route("/application", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Get("/health", ProxyRequestHandler(proxy))

        r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
            if mustBeSecure() {
                r.Use(keycloak.MustStandardKeycloakAuth("url"))
            }
            r.HandleFunc("/*", ProxyRequestHandler(proxy))
        })
    })

    http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:4411", router)
}

func NewProxy(targetHost string) (*httputil.ReverseProxy, error) {
    targetUrl, err := url.Parse(targetHost)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(targetUrl), nil
}

func ProxyRequestHandler(proxy *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Diogo. Thank you for your response. I've been out, thats wy my late response. There is a small misunderstanding. I want  that`/health` is managed by `handleHealth`, but `/application/health`, which is a different endpoint, must be proxied without security. If I understand your proposal right, in the second line, the `r.Get("/health")` is applying to `"/application/health"`, which should be proxied instead.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear before. I've updated the answer with what you expect, also a bit more organized.